# Regular Expression for String *.java

Tags: wildcard

I am writing a program for finding number of occurences of java classes in a log file.

I want to count the number of distinct times a java class is called.
The search should be of the form "*.java"

Can anyone help me with a Regular Expression for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sufficient regular expression would probably look something like `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\\.java` . This regular expression requires the string start with a letter (or underscore), and continue any number of letters or numbers (or underscores), which follows Java class name conventions. The period is double escaped by \\ -- one escaping is so that Java will escape the \ in the String, and the second is so that the regex matcher will escape the period (otherwise period is a special character meaning "any character").

This regular expression would fit the task a little better than what you asked for precisely: `.*\\.java` (which is .java preceded by anything), because that would match the entirety of the line before the ".java", leaving you with 'class names' like "Printing the file from MyClass.java" instead of just "MyClass.java".

I would try this expression out (and try out changes to it) on an online tool like [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/xYa4rkfbxZ).

Comment: Does not work. An example String is as this - at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473). I want it to acknowledge that there is a java class ThreadPool.java and it appears once. The count is still returned as 0

Comment: The regex is essentially correct (check the Rubular link provided). It is very possible that the way you're using the regex isn't quite doing what you think it is, so I'd have to know the surrounding code to help more.

Comment: public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)";
System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST.matches("\\([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9$]*\\.java"));

Comment: Ah, yes, the tricky part here is that String.matches doesn't do quite what you think. String.matches returns true if given regex matches the WHOLE string. Two ways to get around this: (1) put `.*` at the beginning and end of the regex -- this will match anything extra at the beginning or end; or (2) upgrade to the more powerful [Pattern/Matcher API](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) which gives you the semantics you want, and more (like if you want to extract the actual name out).